# Is the time complexity of a loop that simultaneously increments and multiplies $O(\log_k n)$ when $k = 1$?

Tags: time-complexity, asymptotics, proof-techniques

Is the time complexity of `for(int i=0;i<n;i++){i*=k;}` $O(\log_k n)$?

The problem is number 8 from GeeksForGeeks: 
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/practice-questions-time-complexity-analysis/

I trace the program by hand and got stuck. I could not prove that the answer is $O(\log_k n)$. I made a mistake somewhere.

Assume $k = 1$ and $n = 3$:

| n iteration | i = i * k | k = 1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | i = 0 * 1 = 0 | 1 |
|  | i ++ |  |
|  | 1 |  |
| 1 | i = 1 * 1 = 1 |  |
|  | i ++ |  |
|  | 2 |  |
| 2 | i = 2 * 1 = 2 |  |
|  | i ++ |  |
|  | 2 + 1 = 3 |  |

The loop will stop because $i$ is no longer less than $n$.

In general, if $k$ is not known the loop will continue until $i > n$ or $i = n$

What is $i$ if $k = 1$

$i = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, \cdots, = i + 1$

Replacing $i$ with $k$

$i = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, \cdots, = k + 1$

$i = k + 1$

Substituting the value of $i$ into the equation $i = n$

$k + 1 = n$

$k = n - 1$

$\log_k (k) = \log_k (n - 1)$

$1 = \log_k (n - 1)$

$T(n) = \log_k (n - 1)$

Comment: @HereToTryHelp I really appreciate your efforts to edit the question, with 10 edits! Have an upvote.

Comment: I've edited your question, please review it, and hope you can learn from it next time

Comment: @KennethKho, Thank you for taking the time out of your day to edit this question! You could have been doing something else with your time. So, thank you!  I am sorry I have taken a long time to get back to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If k=0 then i is set to 0 inside the loop, so it halts instantly if n <= 1 and runs forever otherwise.

If k=1 then the multiplication has no effect. The loop ends instantly if n <= 0 and after n iterations otherwise.

Let m be the number of iterations starting with m = 0. If k >= 2 then i is set to 0 inside the loop during iteration #0, and to a value i >= k^m during iteration #m. So the loop runs at most as long as k^m < n or m < log_k(n).

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation!

Answer (score 1):

In the incomplete [GeeksForGeeks question #8](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/practice-questions-time-complexity-analysis/), it is only correct when $k > 1, k \in \mathbb{Z}$. The code is equivalent to `for(int i=0;i<n;i=1+i*k)`. We can work out the first few iterations and see:

Iteration #$1$: $i = 1 + 0k = 1$

Iteration #$2$: $i = 1 + 1k = 1 + k$

Iteration #$3$: $i = 1 + (1 + k)k = 1 + k + k^2$

Iteration #$4$: $i = 1 + (1 + k + k^2)k = 1 + k + k^2 + k^3$

Iteration #$5$: $i = 1 + (1 + k + k^2 + k^3)k = 1 + k + k^2 + k^3 + k^4$

Iteration #$x$: $i = 1 + k + k^2 + k^3 + \cdots + k^{x - 1} = (k^x - 1) / (k - 1)$

Now we want to solve $x$ for any given $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

$(k^x - 1) / (k - 1) = n$

$(k^x - 1) = kn - k$

$k^x = kn - k + 1$

$x = \log_k(kn - k + 1)$

$T(n) = O(\log_k n)$

If we don't assume $k > 1$, observe that multiplication by zero will induce infinite loop, and multiplication by one will do nothing, yielding
$T(n) = \begin{cases}
    O(\infty)      & \text{if } \lvert k\rvert = 0, k \in \mathbb{Z}\\
    O(n)           & \text{if } \lvert k\rvert = 1, k \in \mathbb{Z}\\
    O(\log_k n)           & \text{if } \lvert k\rvert > 1, k \in \mathbb{Z}\\
\end{cases}$

Comment: Hi @kenneth-kho,
Thank you so much for taking the time to write the answer.
Thank you for the amount of detail you have put into your answer. 
Writing the equivalent code was the key to my understand. 
Question, when you set (k^x -1)/(k-1) = n, is n the point in the loop where i is greater than or equal to n?
Question, I do not understand why multiplying by zero will induce infinite loop, and multiplication by one with do nothing. Where are you inputting the values of 0 and 1? 
I inputted the values of 0 and 1 into  log base k of (kn -k + 1) and got log base 0 of 1, log base 1 of n.

Comment: @HereToTryHelp You're welcome. Answer to question 1: x is the point in the loop where i is greater than or equal to n. Answer to question 2: since log_k (kn - k + 1) is only valid for k > 1, the formula is invalid here, notice with k = 0, the code becomes `for(int i=0;i<n;i=1)`, and notice with k = 1, the code becomes `for(int i=0;i<n;i++)`, try to convince yourself by plugging k into `for(int i=0;i<n;i=1+i*k)`.

Comment: Hi @kenneth-kho, thank you for taking the time to answer my questions. I finally understand your answers. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @kenneth-kho, how can I learn how to solve problems like you? How did you learn if I may ask?

Comment: @HereToTryHelp I appreciate the answer has been accepted. If you have not been fluent with loops, arrays, recursions, practice with questions. Trace the problem by hand just like what we did, but the solution has to be systematically observed and deduced. Understand that everyone that has made it has gone through this, it is a slow process, but it is the only way, and it is totally doable if you give it time. Once you are more fluent, you can start learning algorithms and data structures (CP4 book) and use them. Once you are fluent with that too, you can start learning really creative stuff.

Comment: Hi @kenneth-kho, you are welcome! Will do. Understand, that is the hard part for me. Thank you, thank you and one more thank you! Thank you sharing the book. Most importantly, thank you for sharing knowledge. I am excited.

Comment: Hi @kenneth-kho, how do you know how to set (k^x -1)/(k-1) equal to n? I maybe wrong, but I was thinking that because the summation of K^x is a geometric series from i = 0 to n is the reason why you knew. Again, I maybe wrong in my thinking.

Comment: @HereToTryHelp We can see the code `for(int i=0;i<n;i=1+i*k)` stops when `i>=n`. We would like to find Iteration #$x$ such that $i = n$, since this is the iteration when the code stops. We know the formula for Iteration #$x$ from the previous paragraph.

Comment: Hi @kenneth-kho, I understand. I finally understand. Thank you!  Thank you! Thank you! Thank you!